# Replace XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, that contain IDs in an attribute called translatedID.

This attribute exists in almost every element in the doc, so instead of searching for each element one by one, I want to select all the translatedID in the document and run some code on each attribute's value.

The needed result is - replacing the translatedID with some other data.

How can I select ALL the translatedID that exists in my XML document?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your XML structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a great case for LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("doc.xml");
var attributes = doc.Descendants().Attributes("translatedID");

foreach (var attribute in attributes)
{
    attribute.Value = DoSomethingWith(attribute.Value);
}

doc.Save("transformed.xml");
```

(That's assuming you want to change the *value* of the attribute. If you want to do something else, that's doable - but you'll need to give more information.)